# Data labels at the beginning being cut off

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to build a chart, but I see that the starting data labels at the beginning being cut off. Not sure what is the reason. I tried using the padding solution but it doesnt seem to work.

My code is based on the C3jS library.

My x-axis padding is :

> padding: {
>           top: 0,
>           bottom: 0,
>           left: 0
>         }

and y axis padding :

> padding: {
>           top: 0,
>           bottom: 0,
>           left: 0,
>           right: 0
>         }

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/8uz8j01j/371/

my code:

```
var stuff = [{
    "year": 2015,
    "month": 12,
    "s1": 0.38,
    "s2": 100,
    "s3": 22.2,
    "s4": 61,
    "s5": -7,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 1,
    "s1": 0.39,
    "s2": 101,
    "s3": 22.12,
    "s4": 62,
    "s5": -6.0,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 2,
    "s1": 0.43,
    "s2": 102,
    "s3": 22.11,
    "s4": 65,
    "s5": -5.7,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 3,
    "s1": 0.40,
    "s2": 103,
    "s3": 22.07,
    "s4": 63,
    "s5": -5.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 4,
    "s1": 0.39,
    "s2": 104,
    "s3": 22.04,
    "s4": 61,
    "s5": -7.0,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 5,
    "s1": 0.38,
    "s2": 105,
    "s3": 22.2,
    "s4": 56,
    "s5": -11.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 6,
    "s1": 0.38,
    "s2": 106,
    "s3": 22.05,
    "s4": 56,
    "s5": -12.8,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 7,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 102,
    "s3": 22.7,
    "s4": 58,
    "s5": -9.7,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 8,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 105,
    "s3": 21.20,
    "s4": 53,
    "s5": -6.2,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 9,
    "s1": 0.35,
    "s2": 108,
    "s3": 20.52,
    "s4": 64,
    "s5": -5.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 10,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 103,
    "s3": 20.92,
    "s4": 62,
    "s5": -3.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 11,
    "s1": 0.36,
    "s2": 107,
    "s3": 21.11,
    "s4": 51,
    "s5": -5.7,
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 12,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 114,
    "s3": 22.08,
    "s4": 56,
    "s5": -8.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 1,
    "s1": 0.35,
    "s2": 103,
    "s3": 22.07,
    "s4": 56,
    "s5": -7.2,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 2,
    "s1": 0.36,
    "s2": 108,
    "s3": 22.2,
    "s4": 63,
    "s5": -9.0,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 3,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 96,
    "s3": 25.67,
    "s4": 62,
    "s5": -9.4,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 4,
    "s1": 0.38,
    "s2": 102,
    "s3": 21.94,
    "s4": 63,
    "s5": -9.5,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 5,
    "s1": 0.35,
    "s2": 114,
    "s3": 22.07,
    "s4": 61,
    "s5": -9.0,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 6,
    "s1": 0.36,
    "s2": 103,
    "s3": 21.51,
    "s4": 54,
    "s5": -9.7,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 7,
    "s1": 0.36,
    "s2": 107,
    "s3": 22.2,
    "s4": 65,
    "s5": -11.3,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 8,
    "s1": 0.35,
    "s2": 108,
    "s3": 20.2,
    "s4": 61,
    "s5": -12.8,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 9,
    "s1": 0.36,
    "s2": 103,
    "s3": 22.15,
    "s4": 50,
    "s5": -8,
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 10,
    "s1": 0.37,
    "s2": 112,
    "s3": 22.07,
    "s4": 65,
    "s5": -9,
  },
];

var colors = {
  data1: '#ff6666',
  data2: '#737575',
  data3: '#27A5CF',
  data4: '#C9BC22',
  data5: '#4D4B39',
  default: '#000000'
};

var filterShade = {
 data1: '#ff666685',
  data2: '#73757587',
  data3: '#27a5cf87',
  data4: '#c9bc228f',
  data5: '#4d4b3985',
  default: '#000000'
}

var xAxisDates = [];

xAxisDates.push('x')
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  xAxisDates.push(stuff[i]["year"] + '-' + stuff[i]["month"] + '-1');
}

var factor = {
  s1: 10,
  s2: 0.08,
  s3: 0.52,
  s4: 0.18,
  s5: 20
};

var vals1 = [];
vals1.push('data1');
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  vals1.push(stuff[i]["s1"] * factor.s1)
};

var vals2 = [];
vals2.push('data2');
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  vals2.push(stuff[i]["s2"] * factor.s2)
};

var vals3 = [];
vals3.push('data3');
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  vals3.push(stuff[i]["s3"] * factor.s3)
};

var vals4 = [];
vals4.push('data4');
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  vals4.push(stuff[i]["s4"] * factor.s4)
};
var vals5 = [];
vals5.push('data5');
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  vals5.push((stuff[i]["s5"] + factor.s5))
};

var chart = c3.generate({
  size: {
    width: 2000,
    height: 1000
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  data: {
    onmouseover: onMouseover,
    onmouseout: onMouseout,
    type: 'spline',
    groups: [
      ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']
    ],
    order: null,
    x: 'x',
    columns: [xAxisDates, vals1, vals2, vals3, vals4, vals5],
    labels: {
      format: {
        data1: function(value, id, i, j) {
          return value / factor.s1 + "%"
        },
        data2: function(value, id, i, j) {
          return Math.round(value / factor.s2);
        },
        data3: function(value, id, i, j) {
          return value / factor.s3 + "%"
        },
        data4: function(value, id, i, j) {
          return Math.round(value / factor.s4) + "%"
        },
        data5: function(value, id, i, j) {
          return (value - factor.s5).toFixed(1);
        }
      }
    },
    colors: {
      data1: colors.data1,
      data2: colors.data2,
      data3: colors.data3,
      data4: colors.data4,
      data5: colors.data5,
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
   show: false,
    format: {
      value: function(value, ratio, id) {
        if (id == 'data1') {
          return value / factor.s1 + "%";
        }
        if (id == 'data2') {
          return (value / factor.s2).toFixed(2);
        }
        if (id == 'data3') {
          return value / factor.s3 + "%";
        }
        if (id == 'data4') {
          return Math.round(value / factor.s4) + "%"
        }
        if (id == 'data5') {
          return (value - factor.s5).toFixed(1);
        }

      }
    },
  },
  axis: {
    y: {

      min: 0,
      max: 60,
      padding: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
      }
    },
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      padding: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
      },
      tick: {
        values: ['2015-12-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-10-01', '2016-12-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-06-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01'],
        format: "%b-%y",

      }
    }
  },
   grid: {
        x: {
            lines: [
                {value: '2017-06-01', text: 'June 17'}

            ]
        }
    },
  padding: {
    right: 30,
    left: 80,
    top: 80
  },
  point: {
    show: false
  }
});

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -20)
  .attr("width", 200)
  .style("text-anchor", "left")
  //.append("xhtml:body")
  .style("font", "14px 'Calibri'")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("line-height", "0.2")
  .html("<h3>ABC Approval of</h3></b><h3>need for speed Strategy</h3></b><h3>(Dec-15)</h3>");

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "xyZero")
  .attr("cx", 80)
  .attr("cy", 970)
  .attr("r", 6);

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data1")
  .attr("cx", 40)
  .attr("cy", 920)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("fill", colors.data1);

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -60)
  .attr("y", 920)
  .attr('class', 'dataLabel')
  .attr("width", 200)
  .html("Data 1<sup>1</sup>");

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data2")
  .attr("cx", 40)
  .attr("cy", 800)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("fill", colors.data2);

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -60)
  .attr("y", 800)
  .attr('class', 'dataLabel')
  .attr("width", 200)
  .html("Data 2<sup>1</sup>");

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data3")
  .attr("cx", 40)
  .attr("cy", 620)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("fill", colors.data3);

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -60)
  .attr("y", 620)
  .attr('class', 'dataLabel')
  .attr("width", 200)
  .html("Data 3<sup>1</sup>");

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data4")
  .attr("cx", 40)
  .attr("cy", 470)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("fill", colors.data4);

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -60)
  .attr("y", 470)
  .attr('class', 'dataLabelBlack')
  .attr("width", 200)
  .html("Data 4<sup>1</sup>");

d3.select("svg").append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data5")
  .attr("cx", 40)
  .attr("cy", 280)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("fill", colors.data5);

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -60)
  .attr("y", 280)
  .attr('class', 'dataLabel')
  .attr("width", 200)
  .html("Data 5<sup>1</sup>");

console.log(d3.select("svg defs"));

var data1 = d3.select("svg defs").append("filter")
  .attr("id", "filter1")
  .attr("height", "130%")
  .append('feFlood')
  .attr('flood-color', filterShade.data1)
  .append('feComposite').append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var filter1 = d3.select("#filter1")
  .append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');


var data2 = d3.select("svg defs").append("filter")
  .attr("id", "filter2")
  .attr("height", "130%")
  .append('feFlood')
  .attr('flood-color', filterShade.data2)
  .append('feComposite').append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var filter2 = d3.select("#filter2")
  .append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var data3 = d3.select("svg defs").append("filter")
  .attr("id", "filter3")
  .attr("height", "130%")
  .append('feFlood')
  .attr('flood-color', filterShade.data3)
  .append('feComposite').append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var filter3 = d3.select("#filter3")
  .append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');


var data4 = d3.select("svg defs").append("filter")
  .attr("id", "filter4")
  .attr("height", "130%")
  .append('feFlood')
  .attr('flood-color', filterShade.data4)
  .append('feComposite').append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var filter4 = d3.select("#filter4")
  .append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var data5 = d3.select("svg defs").append("filter")
  .attr("id", "filter5")
  .attr("height", "130%")
  .append('feFlood')
  .attr('flood-color', filterShade.data5)
  .append('feComposite').append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

var filter1 = d3.select("#filter5")
  .append('feComposite')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');



function onMouseover(elemData) {
  var id = elemData.name;
  if (id == undefined) id = elemData.id;
  var el = d3.select('.c3-chart-texts')
    .selectAll(".c3-chart-text > .c3-texts-" + id + " > .c3-text-" + elemData.index);
  if (id == 'data1')
    el.attr('filter', 'url(#filter1)');

  if (id == 'data2')
    el.attr('filter', 'url(#filter2)');

  if (id == 'data3')
    el.attr('filter', 'url(#filter3)');

  if (id == 'data4')
    el.attr('filter', 'url(#filter4)');

  if (id == 'data5')
    el.attr('filter', 'url(#filter5)');


}

function onMouseout(elemData) {
  var id = elemData.name;
  if (id == undefined) id = elemData.id;
  var el = d3.select('.c3-chart-texts')
    .selectAll(".c3-chart-text > .c3-texts-" + id + " > .c3-text-" + elemData.index);
  el.attr('filter', '')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a min/max configuration also for x axis like below:

```
x: {
    type: 'timeseries',
    min: '2015-11-01',
    max: '2017-11-01',
    ...
}
```